# How to display first page of file in terminal?

Tags: terminal, head

I would like to display as much from a file as possible which still fits in the terminal window, i.e. like a `head` with a dynamic number of lines.

If there are no lines which wrap to multiple lines and the prompt takes a single line then I can achieve that with `head -n $(($(tput lines)-1))`.

Is there a solution that doesn't require the assumptions above?

Edit: The solution should be non-interactive, so e.g. `less` doesn't work as far as I know.

Edit2: The solution should preferably also handle properly non-printing characters like ANSI escape sequences for text coloring.

Answer (score 2):

You can [wrap with `fold`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25174/70524), then `head` it:

```
onepage () {
  fold -w "$(tput cols)" -s "$@" |
    head -n "$(($(tput lines)-1))"
}
```

Or maybe use `pr`. Assuming GNU `pr`:

```
pr -l "$((LINES - 1))" +1:1 -t
```

- `-l ...` - set page height to `$LINES` - 1.
- `+1:1` start printing from the first page ... till the first page.
- `-t` - don't print the header.

Comment: The first solution using `fold` and `head` works nicely expect when prompt is using more than one line. Is there a way to determine that from e.g. `$PS1`? The `pr` solution didn't work properly with lines which wrap to multiple lines.

Comment: @SamuliAsmala not without expanding `PS1` the way the shell expands it completely. If in bash, you could do something like `foo=${PS1@P}; echo ${#foo}` to get the length of the prompt, and then compare it with the width to see if it goes to multiple lines. (or maybe count lines in the expanded prompt)

Comment: Your example doesn't work since I'm using .bash-git-prompt and my prompt is a bit more complicated: `\[\033[0;32m\]✔\[\033[0;0m\] \[\033[0;33m\]\w\[\033[0;0m\] [\[\033[0;35m\]${GIT_BRANCH}\[\033[0;0m\] ↑·2\[\033[0;0m\]|\[\033[0;34m\]✚ 1\[\033[0;0m\]\[\033[1;34m\]⚑ 2\[\033[0;0m\]\[\033[0;0m\]] \n\[\033[0;37m\]$(date +%H:%M)\[\033[0;0m\] $`

Comment: I also noticed that the `fold` solution doesn't work if there are non-printing characters like ANSI escape sequences for text coloring. There is a related question about [Wrap text accounting for non-printing characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/424076/wrap-text-accounting-for-non-printing-characters) which is still unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use the program `less`

In the terminal, type:

```
less nameOfTheTextFile
```

And it will show all available lines that fit, starting from the first line of the text file

Comment: `less` is interactive and doesn't return immediately back to prompt so unless there is a way to change that this method doesn't fit my needs. I've updated the question to be more clear on this.