# Looking for a tool that creates plain text tarball from set of files, they can be mailed in email body

Tags: tar, utilities

I'm looking for a command line tool that takes a tarball, uncompresses and unpacks it, and turns the contents into one contiguous file, comprised of lines that are a maximum of eighty characters wide, so that it can be mailed as plain text without corruption.

Thank you for pointing me to such tool.

Thanks.

Comment: Tarball can be mailed too (w/o any problem). Will you accept such answer?

Comment: An arbitrary file cannot be embedded as-is in e-mail reliably, that's why base64 is used to encode attachments. If you insist on having an "attachment" in the actual body, you can `base64` the tarball by yourself, the recipient will need to `base64 -d` it by hand. E-mail clients do this automatically with actual attachments and it works. Do not unpack the tarball beforehand because it takes care of names and boundaries of the files within, let the recipient do this. So the easiest way is just to attach the tarball. What problem are you trying to solve by willing to invent another way?

Comment: It seems that it would be better to use a MIME-aware mailer client and just attach the tarball

Comment: This feels like an XY problem.  The requested solution won't work for binary files and will corrupt text files too.  In the early days of email, uuencode and split were created specifically to email compressed tarballs.   Now you can just attach them and the MIME format will take care of what uuencode use to do, but you still might need to split it first so the email isn't too big.

Comment: Consider the process, with a "_tarball, uncompresses and unpacks it, and turns the contents into one contiguous file_" - (1) a tarball already is one contiguous file (2) you want to make the content larger by uncompressing it?

Comment: Looks like you want to be using shar instead of tar.

Comment: That's an interesting prospect, @TobySpeight. Didn't that largely go out along with `uuencode` and friends?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. In the case of plain text input, which of the above solutions makes the text in the email actually readable (even if a bit disrupted by the encoding)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer - and may do what you want:

```
tar xf tarball-test.tar.gz --to-stdout | fold -w 80 -s > output.txt 

# alternative: 

tar zxOf tarball-test.tar.gz | fold -w 80 -s > output.txt
```

I used GNU `tar` for this example, but one of the incantations above should work with other `tar` implementations.

In `fold` note that the `-s` option breaks at spaces - if they exist. [See this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25173/how-can-i-wrap-text-at-a-certain-column-size) for alternatives & options to `fold`.

You can test this by creating some files & making a tarball:

```bash
$ for i in {1..25}; do printf 'file1' >> file1.txt; done
$ for i in {1..30}; do printf 'xxfile2' >> file2.txt; done
$ for i in {1..20}; do printf 'file3 ' >> file3.txt; done
$ tar -czf tarball-test.tar.gz file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

<sup>Note that the files created above contain no line breaks. This is unusual, but I didn't want to make assumptions re the OP's files. However, usage of such (non-delimited) files makes the behavior of `fold` undefined. Otherwise, to avoid this risk, create the files with line breaks as shown below.</sup>

```bash
$ for i in {1..25}; do printf 'file1' >> file1.txt; done; printf '\n' >> file1.txt
$ for i in {1..30}; do printf 'xxfile2' >> file2.txt; done; printf '\n' >> file2.txt
$ for i in {1..20}; do printf 'file3 ' >> file3.txt; done; printf '\n' >> file3.txt
$ tar -czf tarball-test.tar.gz file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

Comment: No, that only removes the limitation that lines be under LINE_MAX bytes, they still need to be delimited.

Answer (score 0):

It does as requested, save this to `concat_mailer.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

# extract .tar file containing .txt--merge, format, e-mail

time_stamp=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S")
cat_file="concat_[$time_stamp]"

tar -x -f "$1"

# create single plain text file
for text in *.txt
 do
  cat "$text" >> "$cat_file.txt"
 done

# delimited text captured for output
cat "$cat_file.txt" | fold -w 80 > temp.txt

mv history.log to_append.txt
echo -e "[ "$time_stamp" ] "$1"\n" > history.log
cat temp.txt >> history.log
cat to_append.txt >> history.log

# text piped to email body, via stdin
cat temp.txt | msmtp -a default -t target@email.address


if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    echo -e "\n\033[31mFailed.\033[m\n"
else
    echo -e "\n\033[32mSuccess.\033[m\n"
fi

rm *.txt

exit 0
```

Run this (makes script executable):
`chmod +x concat_mailer.sh`
You only have to do this once.
Usage: `./concat_mailer.sh your_file.tar`
Tested working on Fedora 38.
Making the `mail` command work is harder than I expected.
I ended up making this helper script for `msmtp` [HERE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jaycrav3ns/misc_scripts/main/shellscripts/email_from_console.sh).

Check your path's to `mail` & `sendmail` & `msmtp` by typing:

```
whereis mail; whereis sendmail; whereis msmtp
```

My `sendmail` happened to be in `/usr/sbin/`.  It varies. Change these to your path's, respectively:

```
sudo ln -f -s /usr/sbin/sendmail /usr/bin/mail

sudo ln -f -s /usr/bin/msmtp /usr/sbin/sendmail
```

Now ,`mail` & `sendmail` will use `msmtp` as their MTP service.