# Reformat text to exact width

Tags: text-processing, text-formatting, text

On Ubuntu, how to reformat text to fit width (except final line), adding spaces where necessary? The closest I can get is with `fmt --width=64`, but this does not add the spaces between words.

## Input

- snippet taken from `man zip` with all line breaks removed and double spaces turned into single spaces

```
Do not operate on files modified prior to the specified date, where mm is the month (00-12), dd is the day of the month (01-31), and yyyy is the year. The ISO 8601 date format yyyy-mm-dd is also accepted. For example:
```

## `fold --width=64` output

- breaks words, which is undesirable

```
Do not operate on files modified prior to the specified date, wh
ere mm is the month (00-12), dd is the day of the month (01-31),
 and yyyy is the year. The ISO 8601 date format yyyy-mm-dd is al
so accepted. For example:
```

## `fmt --width=65` output

- almost perfect, but also need to add spaces between words

```
Do not operate on files modified prior to the specified date,
where mm is the month (00-12), dd is the day of the month
(01-31), and yyyy is the year. The ISO 8601 date format
yyyy-mm-dd is also accepted. For example:
```

## Wanted output

- snippet taken from `man zip`
- where the double/triple spaces are inserted is not important to me, as long as the line fits the specified width and the words are more or less evenly-spaced

```
Do not operate on files modified prior to  the  specified  date,
where  mm  is  the  month  (00-12),  dd  is the day of the month
(01-31), and  yyyy  is  the  year.   The  ISO 8601  date  format
yyyy-mm-dd is also accepted.  For example:
```

Comment: that's such an old problem, and there's solution with built-in language features, but it seems nobody wrapped them in a tool. Hm!

Comment: Related? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/766277/227738

Comment: Maybe closer? https://blogs.perl.org/users/damian_conway/2019/08/greed-is-good-balance-is-better-beauty-is-best.html

Comment: GNU/awk is a possibilty. (a) Use `RS=""` to read whole paragraphs at once. (b) Trim off the first 65 chars, and backtrack to a word gap. (c) Insert required n spaces by replacing one space in front of fields (NF - n + 1) to (NF). (d) Repeat {a..c}. (e) Avoid changing the last short line of a paragraph.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant well, the art is in actually implementing that :) I think your comment makes a nice answer, but you'd have to provide a bit of a skeleton for that script

Comment: @MarcusMüller That *is* the skeleton -- the rest is just implementation details ;-)  I am wondering how to put in more than one space per word -- some more arithmetic needed there. I read the perl link above -- very deep analysis there.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant yeah, that's why I opted for a python implementation; basically, how (I think) you'd approach that is 1) if the "deficit" in characters on this line is larger than the number of existing spaces, simply multiply these spaces by an integer factor so that the deficit is between 0 and (number of space - 1).

Comment: @Paul_Pedant 2) After that, you find the ratio of spaces to deficit; if it's larger larger than an integer N, you first add another space to every Nth space. You choose an offset for the first so that long runs of spaces on this line don't align with long runs on the previous.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant 3) After that, you randomly distribute the remaining deficit on the shortest runs of spaces.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant I found that 2) indeed makes the whole thing look prettier, but that skipping 2) after doing 1) was good enough, seeing we're not going to do context-aware spacing nor any kind of ligature / kerning on a monospace font console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to consider using nroff for that job. Here is an example of how to use it with your text in a file named infile:

```
$ 2>/dev/null nroff <(echo .pl 1 ; echo .ll 40) infile
Do  not  operate on files modified prior
to the specified date, where mm  is  the
month  (00‐12),  dd  is  the  day of the
month (01‐31), and yyyy is the year. The
ISO  8601 date format yyyy‐mm‐dd is also
accepted. For example:
```

.pl 1 roff markup sets the page height to a single line, thus disabling pagination.

.ll 40 sets the line length to 40 characters.

nroff is a special markup formatting utility with excellent possibilities for customization.

Comment: really nice! I must admit I've never gotten used to roff, but this is exactly what it's for!

Comment: Is there any reason to use `2>/dev/null`? I see no difference with and without it.

Comment: Is there also any way to not break on hyphenation? (so that `yyyy‐mm‐dd` is on one line with a width of 64 characters per line) I will check the man page for `nroff` in a bit to see if I can answer this myself.

Comment: 2>/dev/null is not strictly necessary. It simply redirects the standard error to /dev/null thus suppressing any possible error messages.

Comment: I believe you can add the .nh directive to disable hyphenation. Try this:
**2>/dev/null nroff <(echo .pl 1 ; echo .ll 64 ; echo .nh) infile**

Comment: @user9101329 the `.nh` directive prevents adding _additional_ hyphenation (for example, breaking `acknowledging` into `acknowledg-<newline>ing`), and still breaks `yyyy-mm-dd` into `yyyy-mm-<newline>dd`

Answer (score 0):

You won't have much joy with this if you don't add support for localized hyphenation; 65 letters is just too short, especially if your text, unlike the excerpt you've used, consists of longer composite words. German and Finnish speakers will hate you if you try to justify a line with 10 letters on it, because it's two words between a 35-letter and a 40-letter word.

Anyways, assuming you don't care *that* much about typography, it's not that hard: Python brings the `textwrap` module, and that does the "breaking into lines of *at most* 65 characters", and all you need to do is add the missing whitespaces.

Something like [**this**](https://gist.github.com/marcusmueller/d65a08b88cd465d1b42439ad1986a920) script. (You're welcome!)

Download the script `justify.py`, (put it somewhere in your `$PATH`, if you don't want to specify the full path to the script), and `chmod 755 /path/to/justify.py`. Then you can run

```bash
echo 'Do not operate on files modified prior to the specified date, where mm is the month (00-12), dd is the day of the month (01-31), and yyyy is the year. The ISO 8601 date format yyyy-mm-dd is also accepted. For example:' \
     | /path/to/justify.py 65 \
     | cowsay -n
```

to get

```
 ___________________________________________________________________ 
/ Do  not operate  on files modified  prior to the specified  date, \
| where  mm  is  the  month (00-12),  dd  is the  day  of the month |
| (01-31), and yyyy is the year. The ISO 8601 date format  yyyy-mm- |
\ dd is also accepted. For example:                                 /
 ------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

I chose to allow it to break on `-`; if you don't want that, modify the `wrapper = textwrap.Textwrapper(…` line to include `break_on_hyphens=False`.